# How to get drop down for possible values in swagger

Tags: java, rest, web-services, swagger, swagger-ui

Hi I have Rest API and used swagger for the test this API.

below is one of my API.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void test(String string){
    // body
}
```

The Possible value for the arguments are "Database" or "Cache".

So i want drop down in swagger view.

I have gone through the google search , i can not found how to implement with java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use **Enum** as your method argument instead of **String**. See below reference:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void test(TestEnum enum) {
    // body
}
```

And below is your **TestEnum**:

```
public enum TestEnum {

    Dropdown1("DropDown1"),
    DropDown2("DropDown2");

    private String str;

    TestEnum(String str){
       this.str = str;
    }

    public String getStr() {
       return str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate your parameter with the possible values

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void test(@ApiParam(allowableValues = "one, two, three") String string) {
    // body
}
```

Comment: its not working, there is text area is display instead of Drop-down.